# Jackson : concatenate several keys for a field

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible when deserializing my Json with Jackson to link several json keys to a single variable of my Java object?

I receive from my Json the attributes `profil_id`,`trimestre_id` and `ap_id`
and I would like to insert all of them in my variable `idApp` of my class `App`.

Example:

`profil_id = "AA"`

`trimestre_id = "BB"`

`ap_id = "CC"`

will return `idApp = "AABBCC"`

For now, my Java class looks like but it returns only `idApp = "AA"`:

```
public class App {

   @Id
   @JsonAlias({"profil_id","trimestre_id","ap_id"})
   @Column(name = "id_app")
   private String idApp;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to Jackson custom deserializer and @JsonDeserialize annotation. You can implement your own deserializer for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoBurla, I was able to move towards the solution you were proposing and it works for me now.